# simplified version of return ((union { float v; uint32_t r; }){(int)x}.r>>21) - 496

Tags: c

I have found some code in malloc.c implementation, can anyone please tell me what does this code actually do:

```
return ((union { float v; uint32_t r; }){(int)x}.r>>21) - 496
```

I did some search and found that it converts integer to IEEE 754 floating point but I am unable to understand how it works. Can anyone please help me in understanding it in multiple steps?

Comment: How much of it do you understand? Is the bit shift and the subtraction of 496 the part that's confusing you? (I like this question, btw. I'm not sure if it's on topic but I find it interesting. :))

Comment: @student You want to tell us what type x is (`size_t`, I guess) and what the return type of the function is (`int` would be my guess here). Otherwise your question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is a [compound literal](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html):

```
(union { float v; uint32_t r; }){(int)x}
```

Basically is a conversion from a variable casted to `int` to a `float` (the first member of the `union`)

Uses this `float` as an `uint32_t`:

```
.r
```

And removes the last 21 bits (mantissa?):

```
>>21
```

then returns the value `-496`

Step by step:

```
union t {
   float v;
   uint32_t r;
};

union t u;

u.v = (int)x;
u.r >>= 21;
return u.r - 496;
```

Comment: No, I think you've missed a crucial point.  Because the initializer list `{(int)x}` contains no member designator, its element initializes the *first* member of the union, i.e. `v`.  That involves a conversion from `int` to `float`.  The result is then read out via member `r`.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a bit hack for computing 4*log<sub>2</sub>x+12, or something pretty close to this value.

The idea is to use hardware to compute binary logarithm, and use bit shifting to harvest the exponent portion of the `float`, along with two upper bits of the mantissa.

I wrote a little test program to compare the computations above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

int makesize(uint32_t x) {
    return ((union { float v; uint32_t r; }){(int)x}.r>>21) - 496;
}

int main(void) {
    for (uint32_t i = 1 ; i != 1000 ; i++) {
        double v = i;
        double x = log(v)/log(2);
        int y = makesize(i);
        int res= 12+((int)floor(4*x));
        printf("%04d : %d,%d (%d)\n", i, y, res, y-res);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/YVngbO)

A run from 1 to 999 produced values within 1 of each other.

Comment: Any speculation on why `x` is cast to `int`, instead of to an unsigned type?  Or indeed, on why it needs to be cast at all?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't know the type of `x`. I wrapped OP's computation in a function, and gave `x` the type of `uint32_t` because I missed the cast in OP's code. OP did not provide a way to look at the original code, so I had to speculate about the type.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm just observing that (1) the logarithm is undefined for negative arguments, (2) since the code comes out of a `malloc()` implementation, `x` is unlikely to have real type, and (3) if `x` has integral type, then the only net effect of the cast is to possibly invoke implementation-defined behavior.  It just occurs to me, however, that maybe `x` has *pointer* type.  That could explain the casting, albeit not why `int` was chosen instead of an unsigned integral type.